# Cannot checkout branch from GitHub forked repository

Tags: git, github

I am trying to checkout a branch from my forked repository but it gives an error:

Repository: https://github.com/tmsblgh/codechecker/tree/issue799

```
MacBook-Pro:codechecker tmsblgh$ git branch -vv
* master acdc482 [origin/master] Merge pull request #1636 from gyorb/version68
MacBook-Pro:codechecker tmsblgh$ git --version
git version 2.17.1
MacBook-Pro:codechecker tmsblgh$ git fetch
MacBook-Pro:codechecker tmsblgh$ git checkout issue799
error: pathspec 'issue799' did not match any file(s) known to git.
Baloghs-MacBook-Pro:codechecker tmsblgh$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/tmsblgh/codechecker.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/tmsblgh/codechecker.git (push)
MacBook-Pro:codechecker tmsblgh$ git checkout issue799
error: pathspec 'issue799' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Comment: Check your remote server by typing `git remote -v`, I am pretty much its pointing to repo you have forked your repo from. If it is, change it to your origin.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Which version of Git are you using?

Comment: git version 2.17.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the local repo doesn't have `origin/issue799`.

```
#fetch the branch
git fetch origin issue799

#see if origin/issue799 exists
git branch -a

#if yes
git checkout issue799

#if not, create the local branch from FETCH_HEAD
git checkout -b issue799 FETCH_HEAD

#the next push after you make some new commits
git push -u origin issue799
```

Answer (score 1):

This branch is perhaps not in your local git setup. Try `git checkout origin/issue799`

P.S.: origin is the remote you are pointing to

Comment: MacBook-Pro:codechecker tmsblgh$ git checkout origin/issue799
error: pathspec 'origin/issue799' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: do `git fetch` to make sure you have everything in local setup. If it doesn't help, try cloning repo again

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a local branch to track the remote:

```
git checkout -b issue799 origin/issue799
```

EDIT (in response to comments):

I don't know why you are getting an error but here's what I did starting from scratch and it seems to work for me:

```
 $ git clone https://github.com/tmsblgh/codechecker.git
 Cloning into 'codechecker'...
 remote: Counting objects: 14825, done.        
 remote: Total 14825 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 14825        
 Receiving objects: 100% (14825/14825), 12.57 MiB | 22.70 MiB/s, done.
 Resolving deltas: 100% (10329/10329), done.

 $ cd codechecker/
 /home/nick/tmp/codechecker

 $ git branch
 * master

 $ git remote -v
 origin https://github.com/tmsblgh/codechecker.git (fetch)
 origin https://github.com/tmsblgh/codechecker.git (push)

 $ git checkout -b issue799 origin/issue799 
 Branch issue799 set up to track remote branch iue799 from origin.
 Switched to a new branch 'issue799'
```

Comment: MacBook-Pro:codechecker tmsblgh$ git checkout -b issue799 origin/issue799
fatal: 'origin/issue799' is not a commit and a branch 'issue799' cannot be created from it

Comment: What does `git remote -v` say?

Comment: MacBook-Pro:codechecker tmsblgh$ git remote -v
origin https://github.com/tmsblgh/CodeChecker.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/tmsblgh/CodeChecker.git (push)